# Why does ReactJS component, which is a function, have to be put in inside tags at the ReactDom.render() method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very very new to ReactJS and JavaScript in general, so I am having difficulty trying to make sense of the syntax.

I have the following very basic component:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'

function Greetings()
{
  return <h1>Hello World</h1>
}
```

which I am trying to render using the below line:

```
ReactDom.render(<Greetings/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Now I am having difficulty trying to make sense of the syntax:

`ReactDom.render(<Greetings/>, document.getElementById('root'))`,
where `Greetings()` is a function.

So what does enclosing it in tags mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is called [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html). By using JSX, you are effectively calling `React.createElement()`. So, if you don't want to use JSX (`<Component>`), you can replace it with `React.createElement(Component)`. In fact, this is what Babel does when you use React: replaces all JSX tags with calls to `React.createElement`.